# Unknown connection to digital counter 4060

Tags: circuit-design

[image: Red dashed circle]

Hey friends! I'm supposed to build this circuit but I'm not really sure what should I do about the thing that is inside the red circle I marked.
Original site is here:
http://www.eeweb.com/blog/extreme_circuits/dicing-with-leds
I have no idea what that triangle means and where does it connect with digital counter 4060. I'd appreciate some explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to look in the datasheet? It is freely available..

Comment: I did but it did not give me reasonable answer what should I do about that triangle. Counter has 16 pins and that triangle looks like it's none of them

Comment: I think you can safely ignore this connection, as it looks like it is denoting some internal split of the reset signal. Placing the pin number (12) before the junction is an additional evidence of that..

Comment: The triangle is sometimes called a "feather" and indicates a logic inversion (an alternative to a bubble). As Eugene indicates, this is internal to the part. It should not have been drawn outside the purple rectangle and need not have been drawn at all.

Comment: @Tut -- the IEEE standard for logic symbols (can't remember the number offhand) specs that the feather goes outside the part rectangle.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel ...You may be correct, but my intention was to refer to the connection to the non-pin that is not an external connection and does NOT belong outside the rectangle. It does little more than confuse the drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangle indicates a logic inversion on the input.

The symbol for the part uses a convention that was invented 20 or so years ago (30?), and was intended to show, on the symbol, *all* you needed to know about the part. Where there are multiple logical functions in the part, these are split apart and shown separately.

In the case of the 4060, it has both an RC oscillator, and a binary counter. The oscillator is shown separately inside its own little box.

Pin 12, the Master Reset, operates to both clear the counter AND to disable the oscillator. The oscillator runs when the reset is low. The convention is that enables are shown in positive logic, so an inverter is shown on that input. As the input goes to two functions, it's shown as two inputs. Helpfully, one doesn't have a pin number on it, to show it's not a real input.

Why don't we see more of this type of diagram? The convention never really caught on, but it is still used. To show diagrammatically all the complexity of some circuits resulted in a few new squiggles being invented, and then combined in difficult to parse ways. Everybody, as soon as they saw one of these symbols, would just head to the data sheet to read what it did. It was an unnecessary complication, and not up to the job. VHDL for design of FPGAs was catching on at the same time, and was far more appropriate for complicated stuff, and simple logic stayed with simple symbols (mostly!).